# Abrir janela de mensagem dentro da página html

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3

Há muito tempo tento fazer isso mais não sei como, tipo, vários sites tem um link que quando clica abre uma janela como se fosse um pop up mais fixa na pagina, mas eu ja tentei de tudo já fucei no codigo fonte dos outros mais nem assim consegui...

não sei se eu posso colocar link aqui, mas é tipo o desse site aqui olha:
http://www.posts.grandesclassicosdocinema.com/2017/06/nineteen-eighty-four-1984-1956.html

dentro da postagem na parte escrita "**DOWNLOAD - ASSINANTES**" quando clica abre a tal janela personalizada...

gente como faz isso, tipo eu atualmente to tendo que usar uma janela de pop up para exibir um pequeno formulario, mas se eu conseguisse fazer essa janelinha ai eu colocaria um "iframe" nela e ficaria bem melhor para acessar... se alguém souber como faz pf ajuda.

Entao na janela ficaria o frame talvez um texto de 2 linhas no maximo e um botao fechar só, agora o tamanho e design eu me viro gente só quero a idéia mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o que você quer fazer é um modal. Com bootstrap da pra fazer bem fácil.
Exemplo aqui: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Segue um exemplo do seu funcionamento: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/)

Comment: perfeito é isso mesmo, eu não sabia que tinha esse nome por isso nao achava em lugar nenhum mto obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que a pergunta já foi respondida, mas só por motivos de aprendizado estou postando este outro cógido, feito 100% no braço.
Com bastante ajuda eu consegui fazer uma simples caixa tipo alert com um botão de fechar, com css e javascript.
Eu digo que é 100 vezes mais prático usar o bootstrap, não sei se é o seu caso, mas eu estou ainda começando a estudar programação, é até divertido e desafiador de aprender como simples programas, ou neste caso uma caixa de alerta/diálogo são feitos parte por parte, ou até mesmo do 0, porém algumas coisas que parecem fáceis acabam se tornando difíceis.
Mas repito, é só por questões de aprendizado.
O código...
São dois arquivos, iframe.php e iframe2.php, teste se quiser.
(o código está praticamente crú, nada que um css não resolva).

iframe.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="janela" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
      <iframe id="iframejanela" name="iframejanela" frameborder="3" style="height: 200px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="alert" id="alert" value="Clique" onClick="javascript: abrir();">
  </body>
</html>
<script language="javascript">
  function abrir(){
    document.getElementById('janela').style.display='';
      window.open('iframe2.php', "iframejanela");
}
</script>
```

iframe2.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
/*Tamanho do alert*/
      .alert{
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #EDEDED;
        color: #000000;
        cursor: default;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
/*Botão de fechar*/
      .closebtn{
        margin-left: 15px;
        color: #000000;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="alert">
        <span class="closebtn" onClick="window.frameElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
            Ação
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```